# EGit treating unchanged files as changed

Tags: git, egit

I'm having a problem with the EGit integration in Eclipse.  Specifically, this is in Renesas E2Studio.  Frequently, if we do a merge or branch switch, EGit will report unstaged changes in files, but they haven't actually changed, only the create date changed.  For example, if I make changes in one branch, commit those files, then switch to a different branch, those same files that I touched in the first branch correctly reverted to the version in the second branch, but now EGit says the files have changed.  The content is 100% identical, and EGit shows zero differences.  The EGit filemode is set to false.  There are no whitespace changes (all files are using CR-LF line terminators).  I'm suspecting since the file dates changed to when the branches were switched, EGit is keying off the file date and sees that it's newer than what was committed.

Is there a way to tell it to ignore the date changes?  It seems to be going off the create date, which does change when I switch branches.  It'a bit of a headache when a merge may cause hundreds of files to have "changed", but only a handful actually have changes to merge in.

Comment: I doubt the assumption that the date matters in (E)Git. Please proof it by touching a file without changing it. Does EGit show zero differences with or without the option _Ignore White Space_ (see right-click menu in the Compare editor)?

Comment: I can touch a file without changing it, but only the modified date changes, the created date doesn't, which is why I said it seems to be going off the create date.  I can edit a file, save it, undo the edit, save it again, and EGit will show no change.  As I already said, THERE ARE NO WHITESPACE CHANGES.  Comparing it with or without "ignore white space" shows no difference.

Comment: What does the CLI git say about the state of the working directory?

Comment: In case you want to proof your assumption: copying a file creates a file with the same content, but with a different creation date. How to reproduce your issue? Were changes made outside of Eclipse and if so, did you press _Refresh_ in the _Git Staging_ view afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm creating a new file  with the same filename with a new create date having the same content will be flagged as an unstaged change.  Again, how do I get Git to disregard the create date?

Comment: Reproducing it with a new Git repository proves your assumption wrong. Again, in Git the create date does not matter. It might related to the executable flag or what ever. We are stuck in an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

Comment: I haven't created a new git repository, I replaced the file in the same working directory with a new file having exactly the same content and filename.  The properties of said file are the same, except for the create date.  Git sees it as change.  There is no change other than the create date.  So apparently, Git does care about create dates.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example with a new Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I have tried but cannot reproduce what you say. I have never seen what you say myself, nor heard it from others. To my knowledge the creation date does not matter in Git.

Comment: I tried repeating this experiment in another Eclipse based tool, and I concur they show no change, as I would exepct.  Apparently there is something unusual in this particular project.  I had thought maybe it was a bug in this particular Renesas toolset, but opening a different project I'm not seeing this behavior.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I think I found the source of my headaches.  I tried creating a different project and was experimenting with git, but it would not show the issue.  Then I added the .gitattributes from our other project, and now it consistently does this.  I have the line "*.c text eol=crlf" in the .gitattributes because source files kept converting to LF automatically.  With this .gitattributes, I'll commit a file, switch to different branch, and that same file now shows that it has a change, but there is no change.  Should I use the core.autocrlf setting instead to make sure files stay as CRLF?

Comment: Great that you found the root cause. I'm not sure what's the best here. Maybe it is also possible without any converting: In Eclipse, you can specify whether to use CRLF or LF in  _Project > Properties: Resource_, in the section _New text file line delimiter_. But this applies not to existing line breaks.